# How should I pass a parameter with space to npm script from Powershell

Tags: powershell, npm-scripts

I am trying to pass a file name that has a space to npm script. For example, if the file name is "A B.text", when I try to run the following command `npm start "A B.txt"` in Powershell, somehow the argument becomes `^A^ B.txt^` when I check the argument in the process object. If I add write file name directly in package.json in the following format instead of passing it from Powershell, I get the expected name in the argument array.

```
...
"start": "node ./dist/main.js \"A B.txt\""
...
```

I have tried using escape character (`) but it does not seem to work.

Comment: sounds like you need the stop parsing character (`--%`). Try `npm start --% "A B.txt"`

Comment: How do you run it in Powershell?

Comment: --% does not seem to work. I run **npm start "A B.txt"**